# Determine the equation of the second order curve

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I am trying to transform the equation of the second order curve to its canonical form and  determine the type of the curve and plot its graph
$2x^2+y^2+4x-6y+11=0$
So I tried to use factoring polynomials
And got this form
$2(x+1)^2+(y-3)^2 = 0$ and actually I know  $9 $ equations from the conic section but this doesn't look like one of them ! So I can't determine the type or graph it where is the mistake!

Comment: The form you got has only $1 \cdot y^2$ but the original has $2y^2.$

Comment: Is $-6x$ supposed to be $-6y?$  It appears so because you already have an $x$ term.  Your standard form is not correct as the constant is $+11$ instead of $+12$.  The form you show is just one point, as the sum of squares is only $0$ if they both are.

Comment: Yea it's-6y but  and I solve it with -6y it's the same ...

Comment: It's -6y ,             And no the coefficient of y² is 1 not 2 if it's 2 it would be easier than to spit :)

Comment: You should edit the correction to the coefficient of $y^2$ into your post.

Answer (score 2):

Now that you have updated the constant term, you have the correct form $$2x^2+y^2+4x-6y+11=0\\2(x+1)^2+(y-3)^2=0$$
When a sum of squares is zero, each square must be zero, so we can say
$$2(x+1)^2=0\\(y-3)^2=0\\x=-1\\y=3$$

so the only solution is the point $(-1,3)$

Comment: Where that 1 came from

Comment: Which $2$?  The one in front of $(x+1)^2$ is just like in your post.  You can expand the squares in the last line to see it matches the first line.

Comment: We have 2(x²+2x+1-1)+ y² -6y+9-9+11=0. Then 2(x+1)²+(y-3)²-11+11= 0

Comment: But you have $12$ as the constant term, which I have copied.  That is where the $+1$ comes from in the second line.  It is what is left when the squared terms use up $11$

Comment: Sorry again it's 11 not 12

Comment: You still have not fixed the $y^2$ coefficient.

Comment: But I don't need point I need an equation like an ellipse  equation  x²/a² + y²/b² = 1  or another but it suppose to be a conic

Comment: A single point is a degenerate form of a conic.  You have that.  The $+1$ and $-3$ just shift the center from the origin.  You have $a^2=\frac 12$.  The right side being $0$ is what makes it a single point as I said.

Comment: Is it the formula of parabola x^2 - a^2 = 0?

Comment: No, $x^2-a^2=0$ is the pair of straight lines $x=\pm a$.  A parabola is of the form $y=ax^2$

Comment: Sorry but by setting the right side equal zero where did that 1/2 came from since we don't have constant any more?

Comment: The $a^2=\frac 12$ came from comparing $2(x+1)^2$ and your $\frac {x^2}{a^2}$.  It is not important to this problem, but it would cause the curve to be an ellipse if the right side were positive.

Comment: So the equation will be x²+1/2=0 ?

Comment: I don't understand that question at all.  What equation?

Comment: The main question was  to transform the equation of the second order curve to its canonical form and determine the type of the curve and plot its graph!

Comment: And I have done that.  The graph is just a point.  You have asked quite a variety of questions here in the comments, usually without enough explanation to understand where they are coming from.

Comment: It's the same questions I asked there but you answer in the comment and I didn't understand that's why I kept asking

Comment: Do you know that squares must be zero or positive, so if you have a sum of squares that is zero, each square must individually be zero?  I added a couple lines.

Comment: @Yola If there were $2(x+1)^2+(y-3)^2 = m$ with $m>0$ you would be able to recognize an ellipse. Right? And to compute its small and large axis. Now imagine $m$ very small, smaller and smaller. What happens with the ellipse? The center doesn't move, but the axis get smaller and smaller. In the present case is $m=0$ - the lengths of both axis are reduced to $0.$ It remains just the center - it is the degenerate conic given in Ross' answer.